# Is the infinite union of closed sets of the same length still closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

The length of each set is not 0. If so, could you please give the proof, if not, please give a counter example. Thx guys.

Comment: What do you mean by the length of a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence $\{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}+1]\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of closed sets with lenght $1$ , it's easy to prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}+1]=(0,2]$, which is not a closed set.

Comment: thx. You have perfectly solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the collection $\{[1+1/n,2+1/n]:n\in \mathbb N\}$ then their union is $\cup_{n \in N}[1+1/n,2+1/n]=(1,3]$ which is noy closed.